# SQL Bitwise operation (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

So in my table i have id and bitwise columns like so

```
+----+---------+
| id | bitwise |
+----+---------+
| 1  | 1       |
| 2  | 6       |
| 4  | 60      |
+----+---------+
```

From my c# code i'm setting these names to these binary values

```
Name1 = 0x0001,
Name2 = 0x0002,
Name3 = 0x0004,
Name4 = 0x0008,
Name5 = 0x0010,
Name6 = 0x0020,
Name7 = 0x0040,
Name8 = 0x0080,
Name9 = 0x0100,
Name10 = 0x0200,
Name11 = 0x0400,
Name12 = 0x0800
```

**I would like to know the best way to extract the specific record for example lets use id=2
and its representing value**

`id=2` should yield `Name2, Name3`

At the moment I'm not sure how I can `select` a bit from the table into the values without a Huge `If` `Else` and `case` `when` Statement.

I'm not asking for you to solve this (unless you want to) I just need to know the next steps
like how to create a list and or if this list needs to reside in a table format

Comment: You should look into the "enum" and "set" types in MySQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those Name values were in a table, you could use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t2.name
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.bitwise | t2.value = t1.bitwise
WHERE t1.id = 2
```

Comment: See how I started my answer with "if". It's a proposed solution. If you can refactor to enums and sets, you can refactor by adding a table.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write out that if statement, like so

```
DECLARE @BitWiseResult varchar(max)

Select @BitWiseResult = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CAST(bitwise as varchar(8)),len(CAST(bitwise as varchar(8))) -1 , len(CAST(bitwise as varchar(8)))) like '1' THEN 'Name1, ' END 
                + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CAST(bitwise as varchar(8)),len(CAST(bitwise as varchar(8))) -1 , len(CAST(bitwise as varchar(8)))) like '2' THEN 'Name2, ' END
                + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CAST(bitwise as varchar(8)),len(CAST(bitwise as varchar(8))) -1 , len(CAST(bitwise as varchar(8)))) like '4' THEN 'Name3, ' END
...
....
.....           
FROM TableWithBitwiseNumber
WHERE id = 2
```